# Android TextView перенос слов

Tags: android, textview, перенос-слов

Имеется текст (он всегда разный и берётся из API). Он должен занимать максимум  3 строки (в зависимости от размера текста).

Текст у меня, как и положено, занимает 3 строки, но по правому краю он обрезается и получается что-то типа такого
"Немецкий седан би
автомобиль едет пл
удобен и практиче"
Как это исправить и добиться нормального переноса по словам?

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productitem_seller_comments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minLines="3"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="9dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        />
```

Когда ширину я задаю, например 250dp, то слова переносятся нормально.

Comment: Скрин бы результата

Comment: А как его сюда прикрепить?

Comment: Cделайте скриншот, на toolbar найдите Изображение и прикрепите

Comment: Обрезается явно потому, что надо привести в порядок разметку

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853192/prevent-word-break-in-a-textview